# Looking for an unbounded, queue-based, concurrent implementation of java.util.Set

Tags: java, concurrency, set, java.util.concurrent

I'm looking for an implementation of java.util.Set with the following features:

1. Should be concurrent by no means of synchronized locking; So it's obvious that I don't want to use [Collections.synchronizedSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet%28java.util.Set%29)().
2. Should keep insertion order. So ConcurrentSkipListSet is not preferable, because it uses compareTo() as equals(), and requires to provide either an implementation of Comparable or Comparator. There is also a [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](http://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/) which in spite of LinkedHashMap, doesn't keep insertion order.
3. Should be unbounded.
4. Recommended be a FIFO linked list, as my operations are done only to the first element of the queue.

As far as I could find the only proper impl is [CopyOnWriteArraySet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html), but it states in the documentation that:

> Mutative operations (add, set, remove,
>   etc.) are expensive since they usually entail copying the entire
>   underlying array.

In my case, I have lots of insertions to the end of queue (set) and lots Any deletions (and read) from head of the queue. So, any recommendation?

Comment: I think you might have to implement your own.

Comment: "keep insertion order" doesn't sound like a Set. Are you sure you want a Set and not a Queue?

Comment: @Ryan, yes, to be more precise I want to keep ordering of non-duplicate insertions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concurrent Set Queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120495/concurrent-set-queue)

Comment: @Mohsen why would do the insertion in the first place?

Comment: @Woot4Moo, thanks for dup detection. I wasn't able to find that post. I want insertion at the last element, because I want a FIFO.

Comment: Also similar to [Concurrent LinkedHashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698217/concurrent-linked-hashmap-java/2699818#2699818), which asked for a was FIFO only map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following solution has a race condition on removal. It also behaves somewhat differently from standard JDK Set implementations.

However, it uses standard JDK objects, and is a simple implementation. Only you can decide whether this race condition is acceptable, or whether you're willing to invest the timee to find/implement a solution without races.

```
public class FifoSet<T>
{
    private ConcurrentHashMap<T,T> _map;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T> _queue;

    public void add(T obj)
    {
       if (_map.put(obj,obj) != null)
          return;
       _queue.add(obj);
    }

    public T removeFirst()
    {
       T obj = _queue.remove();
       _map.remove(obj);
       return obj;
    }
}
```

Some more explanation: the `ConcurrentHashMap` exists solely as a guard on the `ConcurrentLinkedList`; its `put()` method is essentially a compare-and-swap. So you ensure that you don't have anything in the map before adding to the queue, and you don't remove from the map until you remove from the queue.

The race condition on remove is that there's a space of time between removing the item from the queue and removing it from the map. In that space of time, add will fail, because it still thinks the item is in the queue.

This is imo a relatively minor race condition. One that's far less important than the gap in time between removing the item from the queue and actually doing something with that item.

Comment: @Mohsen - are you saying that the current code needs to have locks added, or are you talking about the locks inherent in ConcurrentHashMap and ConcurrentLinkedQueue? If the former, the answer is no. If the latter, the answer is "good luck."

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The ordering of calling put-add and remove-remove does the trick. I was talking about locks for your two methods. BTW, can you explain more about race condition on removeFirst method. When does it happen?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Race condition mentioned in removeFirst is completely acceptable in my case.

Comment: Its worth noting that by using ConcurrentHashMap.put() you are replacing the current value with the new one even if you decide not to add it to the queue. This only matters if you want to be able to retrieve the original elements from the map at some point. Using putIfAbsent would fix this.